# Why do I get the error "object of type 'closure' is not subsettable" when assigning a data frame in R?

Tags: r, syntax-error, iris-dataset

I am using the iris dataset included in R. First, I created new data using "virginica" and "not virginica" out of out the species column so that every species that wasn't virginica was renamed:

```
data2 <- iris
data2$Species <- factor("virginica",levels=c("virginica","notvirginica"))
data2$Species[iris$Species!="virginica"] <- "notvirginica"
```

Then when I try to create a data frame to represent all species of virginica in my code below, I get the error `"object of type 'closure' is not subsettable"` in `df(Species == "virginica", )`.

```
virg <- df(df$Species == "virginica",)
```

I know theoretically what this error means, but I don't see how it applies to this line. I tried changing the parentheses to brackets and using `iris$Species == "virginica"` instead of `df$Species == "virginica"`, but neither worked. What's going on?

Comment: You are using `df` as if it is a data frame, but it isn't. You haven't defined a data frame called `df`. Your data frame is called `data2`. The only object called `df` is therefore the built-in function `df`, which is why R thinks you are trying to subset a closure. I am voting to close as a typo.

Answer (score 1):

You should use any of these options. For subsetting you can use `[]` or `subset()` function. I do not know where is `df` if you have `data2` and also the use of `()` is not correct for subsetting:

```
#Code 1
virg <- data2[data2$Species == "virginica",]
#Code 2
virg <- subset(data2,Species == "virginica")
```

Comment: This makes so much more sense. I don't know why I thought using df would work here. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using `filter` from the `dplyr` package instead to subset your data? Since the input isn't modified, you can save it using `virg <- iris %>%`.

```r
library(datasets)
library(dplyr)

iris %>% 
  filter(Species == "virginica") %>% 
  head(10)

#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
#> 1           6.3         3.3          6.0         2.5 virginica
#> 2           5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9 virginica
#> 3           7.1         3.0          5.9         2.1 virginica
#> 4           6.3         2.9          5.6         1.8 virginica
#> 5           6.5         3.0          5.8         2.2 virginica
#> 6           7.6         3.0          6.6         2.1 virginica
#> 7           4.9         2.5          4.5         1.7 virginica
#> 8           7.3         2.9          6.3         1.8 virginica
#> 9           6.7         2.5          5.8         1.8 virginica
#> 10          7.2         3.6          6.1         2.5 virginica
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `%in%`

```
subset(data2, Species %in% "virginica")
```